# View TFS changesets in Visual Studio similar to TortoiseHg

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, mercurial, tortoisehg, changeset

I've grown accustomed to reviewing file version history in TortoiseHg where I can right click on a file and show history. It gives me every change to that file across branches and repos in one linear history and gives me a summary comparison. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS3xt.png)

I now need to use Visual Studio and TFS to review changesets and I don't find it as intuitive. This there a plugin or extension that allows me to view TFS changesets in a similar way to the Tortoise line of version control clients?

I've looked at TFS Power Tools, but that still just provides the default VS review options from Windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The [history](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245475%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) feature in Team Explorer allows you to follow merges and it also provides the [track changeset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405662%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) where you can see the origin of a specific change and trace it through multiple branches. However, I haven't seen any plugins that provide the visual representation you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I haven't looked at the track changeset window before. It is a step in the right direction.